# vue state transition with array data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transition, gsap

I want to build a state transition based on the "Animating State with Watchers" in the vue.js docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html#Animating-State-with-Watchers

I understand the example with primitive datatypes. In my case the data numbers, which I need to animate, are values in objects stored in an array.

Here is a simplified example of my problem:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#animated-bar-demo',
  data: {
    bars: [
      {
        width: 30,
      },
      {
        width: 10,
      },
      {
        width: 70,
      },
    ]
  },
  // HOW TO WATCH AND ANIMATE BARS.WIDTH FOR EACH BAR?
  
  /* computed: {
    animatedNumber: function() {
      return this.tweenedNumber.toFixed(0);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    number: function(newValue) {
      TweenLite.to(this.$data, 0.5, { tweenedNumber: newValue });
    }
  }, */
  methods: {
    changeData() {
      let bars = this.bars;
      bars.forEach(bar => {
        bar.width += 10;
      });
      this.bars = bars;
    },
  },
})
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.bar-container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 32px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.bar {
  width: 120%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FA7268;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div id="animated-bar-demo">
  <button v-on:click="changeData()"> add data </button>
    <div class="bar-container" v-for="bar in bars">
        <div class="bar"
            :style="{ 'width': bar.width + '%'}">   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've commented the computed and watch logic for primitive values in my example out. How to watch and animate the width of each bar in the bars array?

I really appreciate your help and explanation for this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found a solution to iterate an array through the tweenLite method but I got it to work.

I've created a component for the bar element and passing a single object width the width included.

Maybe someone with the same problem finds this solution helpful.